# Git : creating new branch while working on another branch will erase all changes?

Tags: git, github

So say I create a new branch from master, called branchA. I make changes in few files. I get a new task allotted. I switch to the master branch, create a new branch called branchB. I make changes in branchB, push the code. Later I switch to branchA, I dont see my old changes (I had not added or committed the files). So whats the procedure here, as I'm new to GIT. Should I add/stage or add/stage and commit files in a branch before switching ?  Thank you

Comment: You should add then commit changes before switching to mater. You can also use `git stash` command to just stash changes. Using `git stash apply` you can bring your stash back.

Comment: Changes you have not *committed* are *not in Git*. When you switch branches with changes active, those changes continue to be *not in Git*. When you then commit on the other branch, those changes are now "in" the other branch (now they *are* in Git) and so they're backed out (left only in the commit at the end of the other branch) when you switch back. This glosses over a LOT of detail; see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) for the details. Note that `git stash` works by making commits.

Answer (score 1):

Before switching to master, you should `add` and then `commit` changes.
If you are not willing to make a `commit`, you can `stash` changes and bring them back later.

To stash changes you can use this command:

```
git stash
```

To bring back the changes in your last stash you should use this command:

```
git stash apply
```

This command will list all of your stashes:

```
git stash list
```

You can use the id of each stash in the list to bring them back.

Answer (score 0):

You can stash your previous changes to save them for later

***to save***

```
git stash
```

***to apply the saved stash***

```
git stash apply
```

for more [details](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)